# ListModel content not set properly

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I have the following code. It basically builds a dialog with a TableView in it, in which I can set values manually in the cells:

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Window 2.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 538
    height: 360

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent

        onClicked: {
        dial.open()
        }
    }

    Dialog {
        id:dial
        width: 300
        height: 500
        title: "Set Path Parameters"
        standardButtons: StandardButton.Ok | StandardButton.Cancel
        signal updSig(var content)

            ListModel {
                id: streetsModel
                property int count: 100
                Component.onCompleted: {
                    for (var i=1 ; i<= count ; ++i)
                        streetsModel.append({"street_alias":"str_"+i , "start_xstart_y": "", "end_xend_y": "", "width": ""})
                }

                //todo: erste Spalte auch einbeziehen
                function getColumnContent(role) {

                    var cont = ""
                    for (var i=0 ; i< count ; ++i) {

                        var cellContent;
                        cellContent = streetsModel.get(i).role
                        //streetsModel.get(styleData.row).role

                        if(!(cellContent === "") && !(cellContent === undefined))
                            cont += cellContent === "" ? "" : (cellContent + "\n")
                    }

                    cont = cont.slice(0,-1)
                    return cont
                }

            }


            Item {
                anchors.fill: parent

                Component {
                    id: editableDelegate

                    Item {

                        TextInput {
                            id: textinput
                            width: parent.width
                            anchors.margins: 4
                            anchors.left: parent.left
                            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                            text: styleData.value
                            color: styleData.textColor

                            MouseArea {
                                id: mouseArea
                                anchors.fill: parent
                                hoverEnabled: true
                                onClicked: textinput.forceActiveFocus()
                            }

                            onEditingFinished: {

                                var role = styleData.role
                                streetsModel.set(styleData.row, {role: textinput.text})
                                console.log(streetsModel.get(styleData.row).role)
                                console.log(styleData.row, role)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
                TableView {
                    id: streetsTab
                    model: streetsModel
                    anchors.margins: 12
                    anchors.fill:parent

                    TableViewColumn {
                        id: strt_al_cl
                        role: "street_alias"
                        title: "Street Alias"
                        width: 120
                    }
                    TableViewColumn {
                        id: start_xy_cl
                        role: "start_xstart_y"
                        title: "StartX,StartY"
                        width: 120
                    }
                    TableViewColumn {
                        id: end_xy_cl
                        role: "end_xend_y"
                        title: "EndX,EndY"
                        width: 120
                    }
                    TableViewColumn {
                        id: width_cl
                        role: "width"
                        title: "Width"
                        width: 120
                    }

                    itemDelegate: {
                        return editableDelegate;
                    }
                }

            onAccepted: {

                var content = [streetsModel.getColumnContent(start_xy_cl.role), streetsModel.getColumnContent(end_xy_cl.role), streetsModel.getColumnContent(width_cl.role)];
                updSig(content)
                this.close()
            }

            onRejected: this.close()
        }
}
```

Now, if I set the values `1` in cellnumber `(0,0)`, `2` in cellnumber `(0,1)` and `3` in cellnumber `(0,2)` (and click on an arbitrary other cell after that to insert the content), I get as content in my onAccepted-method `[3,3,3]`. This means the values for the first two roles `start_xstart_y` and `end_xend_y` get overwritten by the third role value for the role `width`. Why is this? If the code is run, on the console, the correct values in the cells are printed (see the `console.log(...)` parts), which stem from the model directly. So I don't understand why they are finally overwritten

Comment: First of all you should minimize your example to [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). With high probability the problem will be found during this process. Also try to run your code with the last Qt version.

Comment: Where does it violate mcv?

Comment: I've never said it violates some rules. But lots of problem could be solved during minimizing the problem code and concentrating on it. For example `Dialog` or `MouseArea` in your code are unnecessary and doesn't relate to the issue. If you will fail to find the problem one of people here could test it without thinking what is that.

Comment: Ok, so the 'm' is viloated. But it's no big deal, as I've worked around it by building a c++ helpermodel in the background, that stored the correct values.